# Correctly count number of lines a bash variable

Tags: bash, shell, wc

I need to count the number of lines of a given variable. For example I need to find how many lines `VAR` has, where `VAR=$(git log -n 10 --format="%s")`.

I tried with `echo "$VAR" | wc -l)`, which indeed works, but if `VAR` is empty, is prints `1`, which is wrong. Is there a workaround for this? Something better than using an `if` clause to check whether the variable is empty...(maybe add a line and subtract 1 from the returned value?).

Comment: you want to exclude all empty lines or only if there is a single empty line?

Comment: `git log` produces either nothing, either some lines. So I need to treat the case of an empty var, because there won't be blank lines if the variable is not empty.

Comment: It's not true! `git log -n 10` do generate empty lines.  but I get what you want.

Comment: Sorry I haven't written the complete example. I am using format, so I don't have empty lines: `git log -n 10 --format="%s"`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `wc` counts the *number of newline chars*. You can use `grep -c '^'` for counting lines.
You can see the difference with:

```
#!/bin/bash

count_it() {
    echo "Variablie contains $2: ==>$1<=="
    echo -n 'grep:'; echo -n "$1" | grep -c '^'
    echo -n 'wc  :'; echo -n "$1" | wc -l
    echo
}

VAR=''
count_it "$VAR" "empty variable"

VAR='one line'
count_it "$VAR" "one line without \n at the end"

VAR='line1
'
count_it "$VAR" "one line with \n at the end"

VAR='line1
line2'
count_it "$VAR" "two lines without \n at the end"

VAR='line1
line2
'
count_it "$VAR" "two lines with \n at the end"
```

what produces:

```
Variablie contains empty variable: ==><==
grep:0
wc  :       0

Variablie contains one line without \n at the end: ==>one line<==
grep:1
wc  :       0

Variablie contains one line with \n at the end: ==>line1
<==
grep:1
wc  :       1

Variablie contains two lines without \n at the end: ==>line1
line2<==
grep:2
wc  :       1

Variablie contains two lines with \n at the end: ==>line1
line2
<==
grep:2
wc  :       2
```

Comment: Great suggestion using `grep -c '^'` for this.

Answer (score 6):

You can always write it conditionally:

```
[ -n "$VAR" ] && echo "$VAR" | wc -l || echo 0
```

This will check whether `$VAR` has contents and act accordingly.

Comment: It was a bit long, that's why thought there is some better way.

Comment: As soon as it gets this quirky I'd probably take the safe route and write it explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

For a pure bash solution: instead of putting the output of the `git` command into a variable (which, arguably, is ugly), put it in an array, one line per field:

```
mapfile -t ary < <(git log -n 10 --format="%s")
```

Then you only need to count the number of fields in the array `ary`:

```
echo "${#ary[@]}"
```

This design will also make your life simpler if, e.g., you need to retrieve the 5th commit message:

```
echo "${ary[4]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
echo "$VAR" | grep ^ | wc -l
```

Comment: :) or simpler: `grep -c '^'` - see my answer.. ;)